# I am looking forward to handle the errors for the sets of integers

Tags: python

The scenerio is: I’m asking user to input only 5 numbers between 1 and 5 but how do we fix if he input 6 or more and 1 or less and also how to repeat the program again and again if he inputted negative integers like -1,-2. Also, if he input strings, I want to show the users to input only integers

```
Num = [0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range (5):
    Num[i] = int(input("Put the numbers only between 1 and 5!”))
print("Your numbers are ", Num)
```

I tried try except value error but I’m not sure how to put it and expected program to run without errors

Comment: If you need it to restrict the input to be in the range 1-5, you actually can just add a variable and set the input into it i.e. `a = input()` then next line will be `if a in [1:6]:` then you can do the logic `num[i] = int(a)`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
Num = [0,0,0,0,0]

count = 0
while count < 5:
  num = int(input("Put the numbers only between 1 and 5!"))
  if num > 0 and num < 6:
    Num[count] = num
    count += 1
  else:
    print("You must enter values from 1 to 5!")
  
print("Your numbers are ", Num)
```